# Unexpected result of ++((unsigned)x), x is uint8_t?

Tags: c, gcc

Why doesn't this piece of code result in `y == 0x100`?

```
uint8_t x = 0xff;
unsigned y = ++((unsigned)x);
```

Check it out for yourself here: http://codepad.org/dmsmrtsg

Comment: I get `error: lvalue required as increment operand`. The code isn't valid C (>= 99).

Comment: @YoussefG. - it defaults to `int` if you have no type

Comment: @YoussefG. @Mike `unsigned` and `unsigned int` denote the same type. `unsigned` by itself is a complete type. There was a real and different "defaults to `int`" in the past, but that is gone, and is not what's going on here.

Comment: @Mike I think my comment may have been confusing. `unsigned` and `unsigned int` are two different ways of specifying the same type. That's not new in C99. In this particular case, the meaning would be the same if your explanation were strictly correct. I only clarified because in other cases, based on your explanation, you or others could draw incorrect conclusions. (Your link doesn't appear to be about C, BTW.)

Comment: @Mike You can't have `typedef int i; unsigned i x;`, for example. That's because `unsigned` already names a type, it is not a modifier that could be applied to `i`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code you posted is invalid form the point of view of C language. The result of any cast in C is an rvalue. It cannot be used as an argument of `++`. Operator `++` requires an lvalue argument. I.e. expression `++((unsigned) x)` is non-compilable in standard C language.

What you actually observe in this case is GCC's "generalized lvalues" extension

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.4/gcc/Lvalues.html

Per that extension (and contrary to the standard C), a cast applied to an lvalue produces an lvalue. When you attempt to write something into the resultant "generalized" lvalue, the value being written is converted *twice*: it is first converted to the type specified by the explicit cast, and then the intermediate result is converted again to the type of recipient object. The final result is placed into the recipient object.

For example, if with your `x` you do

```
(unsigned) x = 0x100;
```

it will be actually interpreted by GCC as

```
x = (uint8_t) (unsigned) 0x100;
```

and the final value of `x` will be `0`.

And this is exactly what happens in your example. In GCC your

```
++((unsigned) x)
```

is equivalent to

```
(unsigned) x = (unsigned) x + 1;
```

which is in turn interpreted by GCC as

```
x = (uint8_t) (unsigned) ((unsigned) x + 1);
```

This is why you get `0` in `x` as the result, and that is the `0` that then gets assigned to your `y`.

This extension is referred to as *deprecated* by GCC docs.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. Codepad just swallows the code without any warning, I should have tried it with gcc myself...

Comment: @Bart: Yeah... ideone also swallows it even in "C99 strict" mode.

Answer (score 1):

To start this is not valid C code, I don't know how you got it to compile, but your link does show an output, so I'll try to explain what's happening based on this one **major** assumption:

---

I guess with this line `unsigned y = ++((unsigned x));` the second `unsigned` is being dropped by your compiler, hence why you're able to build.

---

So, Assuming that...

```
uint8_t x = 0xff;    // 8 bit value, max is 255(10) or 0xFF(16)
unsigned y = ++((unsigned)x);
```

Now `x` has the max value already for its type. You want to know why if we +1 via `++`, `y` doesn't get value of `0x100`.

`x` is 8 bit, typecasting it doesn't change the fact that it's 8 bit. So when we say:

```
++x
```

We're incrementing `x` (`x=x+1`). So we have an unsigned 8 bit value, at the max and add 1 to it, now it's wrapped around to 0. So `y` will get 0.

If you wanted this to work you could do something like:

```
int main(void) 
{
    unsigned char x = 0xFF; //I'm using char because it's 8 bit too
    unsigned int y = 1+x;   //no need to typecast, we're already unsigned
    printf("%#x %#x\n", x, y);
    return 0; 
}
```

Now you'll get the expected values (`x==0xFF` and `y==0x100`)

Comment: The code isn't valid C, so I don't know how you managed to come up with an explanation.

Comment: @Lundin - I'm reading this question as "why do I get the output I do at the given link". The output is 0. So OP has some non-standard compiler that allows this (is my assumption). Conceptually, it's the explanation I gave, why he can compile and get that output? I have no idea, but that seems like a different topic.

Comment: @Lundin - Since you pointed it out, and it wasn't clear what I was thinking, I clarified this in my post. I assume that's acceptable now?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
uint8_t x = 0xff;
unsigned y = ((unsigned)x) + 1;
```

It will come out as you expect, because `(unsigned) x` is now the **two-byte** value `0x0100`.

Now try this:

```
uint8_t x = 0xff;
++x;
```

The value of `0xff` *wraps around* to `0x00`.

Answer (score 0):

I put in some little *transparency* code into your excerpt and it explains everything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h> // not needed

int main(void) {
  uint8_t x = 0xff;
  printf("%d\n", sizeof(x));
  unsigned y = ++((unsigned)x); 
  printf("%d\n", sizeof(y));
  printf("0x%x\n", y);
  printf("%d\n", sizeof(y));
  return 0;
}
```

and the output is

```
1      // size of x
4      // size of y before computation
0x100  // computed value of y from your code
4      // size of y after computation
```

First thing to notice is that the `sizeof(y)` stays constant across computation.
From the outputs,

- `uint8_t` = 1 byte
- `unsigned` = 4 bytes

When you do a cast in C, think of it as an implicit call to `realloc` which says: "take this data I have from its block, increase (or decrease) its size in memory to the size I want to cast it to, then return the same data in a new block.

And from our sizes, `unsigned` will have enough space to fit the result of the computation from a one-byte operation.

Re-explainng your code in byte-level detail,

```
x               = 11111111                         = 0xff  (in a byte)
(unsigned)x     = 00000000000000000000000011111111 = 0xff  (in a word)
++((unsigned)x) = 00000000000000000000000100000000 = 0x100
```

Comment: I tried this on OS X's llvm-gcc and a gcc on a RedHat distro.

Comment: I just checed the vanilla gcc (GNU's) that comes with OS X's Intel PCs and it compiles too.

Comment: My MinGW's gcc (v 4.6.2, x86) errors out requiring an `lvalue` for `++`, which `(unsigned)x` is not and should not be. Are there some extra options/features enabled in gcc?

Comment: you can move the `++` to the other side of `(unsigned)x` and it would work fine. The difference is subtle but nothing to affect this example